# Why do I see the text late when I move the screen on Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, storyboard

I am a beginner in `iOS` development. There was a problem developing the current project. Characters will be displayed too late when moving the screen. I've just run a normal screen shift. Why is this happening?

**startViewController.swift**

```swift
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
            if response {
                print(response , ": granted")
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
                { (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        print(granted, ": is granted")
                        self.moveScreen()
                    } else {
                        print(granted, ": is not granted")
                        self.moveScreen()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(response , ": not granted")
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
                { (granted, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if granted == true {
                             print(granted, ": is granted")
                             self.moveScreen()
                        }
                        else {
                            print(granted, ": is not granted")
                            self.moveScreen()
                        }
                    } else {
                        print(error as Any)
                        }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func moveScreen(){
        let mainViewScreen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
        mainViewScreen?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
        self.present(mainViewScreen!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**MainViewController.swift**

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit


class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainSecondText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var takeWalletText: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var makeWalletText: UIButton!


    @IBAction func takeWallet(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        changeFontSize()
    }

    func changeFontSize() {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        if screenWidth < 375 {
            // iPhone 4inch and 3.5inch. Smaller than iPhone 8
            // Call change font
            mainText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            mainSecondText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

            takeWalletText.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
            makeWalletText.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

        }
        if screenHeight > 667 {

            mainText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            mainSecondText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

            takeWalletText.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            makeWalletText.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        }
    }

}
```

**low loading Screen**

[image: loading]

**Storyboard**

[image: storyboard]

I was ran drag after the right on the screen, clicked, clicked on a `show` after release on the screen to moved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling `moveScreen` in a completion handler from the notification permission request - You need to dispatch this onto the main queue `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}` - You should try and avoid writing code that uses screen dimensions - it becomes difficult to maintain as new devices are released.  You should also support dynamic type rather than using fixed font sizes.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. `DispatchQueue.main.async` is wokrd!!!! By default, there is no such content in the mobile document. Why should we do this? Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: And @Paulw11. You said you should support dynamic types instead of using fixed font sizes, how can you do that? May I have your code, please?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a case of "please give me the code".  There is a fair bit to learn about the iOS platform in order to create good apps.  There are lots of great videos from Apple from previous WWDCs and other tutorials out there - This can get you started on what dynamic type is and why you should use it -https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically

Comment: If so, do not use async when moving the screen for basic documents. Why should I use this? Is my code wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question - You have an asynchronous call back from the notification permission request; that closure isn't running on the main queue so you need to dispatch your UI update onto the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think it's because I'm a beginner of iOS. Which part is asynchronous? 'center.requestAuthorization (options: [)Are these the asynchronous parts?

Comment: Yes, because the user will take some time to respond to the prompts; when they do the closure is executed.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for sharing a lot of knowledge.

Comment: In addition, @Paulw11 I saw the size of the letter that you linked me. I don't think I can put this part into practice. Because the company decided the size of the letter to me through Jafflin, I cannot change it at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the help of **@Paulw11**. My problem was, when I set an NSNotification, I was calling it as an asynchronous request. That's why my screen makes a delay for the text message to came out late. This is resolved by asynchronously exchanging function execution.

```swift
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
                { (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        print(granted, ": is granted")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                    } else {
                        print(granted, ": is not granted")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                    }
                }
```